# How to reorder rows of DataRow[] by looking up a dictionary?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

//The collection "fields" contain a set of rows with a column "FieldId"

```
DataRow[] fields = GetFields();
```

//This dictionary contains a set of key value pairs. keys represent FieldId's and values represent OrderId's

```
Dictionary<string, int> orders = new Dictionary<string, int>();
orders = LoadOrders();
```

I need to reorder the "fields" collection in the order of OrderId's in the dictionary. The dictionary should be used as a cross reference to look up the FieldId and get the OrderId.

```
Sample data in fields:

Books
Movies
Electronics

Sample data in orders:

<Books, 2>
<Movies, 3>
<Electronics, 1>

The output by reordering the "fields" should be :

Electronics
Books
Movies
```

If anyone has any ideas on this, can you please share? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var res = fields.OrderBy(x => orders[x.Field<string>("FieldId")]).ToArray();
```

Or, if you prefer an in-place sort:

```
Array.Sort(fields,
          (a,b) => orders[a.Field<string>("FieldId")]
                   .CompareTo(orders[b.Field<string>("FieldId")]));
```

Of course you need to be sure that `orders` dictionary contains all the values present in `fields` collection.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do we need the ToArray() to make the res as DataRow[] ?

Comment: Yes, but not in the second case because the `fields` array is sorted without creating a new array.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to the rescue!

```
var results = fields.OrderBy(field => orders[field["FieldID"]]);
```

Comment: `field["FieldID"]` returns object, you need to cast it to string.

Comment: @digEmAll Given that I don't know the structure of his datatable I assumed he could handle getting the field ID out of it in whatever manor he is most comfortable with.  It's tangential to the post.

Comment: Well, I tend to post code that compiles, that's the reason of my suggestion. However, I agree that the quantity of information of the answer does not increase too much by adding a "ToString()" or "as string" piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from entry in myDict 
              orderby entry.Value ascending 
              select entry)
              .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```